# log4j logging not showing on cross project application?

Tags: java, maven, log4j, pom.xml

Intro: 
I have several projects: proj-a, proj-b, proj-c, and etc. These projects are connected through their pom.xml in the dependencies.

Now my problem is this:
proj-a is the main framework project where everything common about all the projects are there. Thus my static log handler is contained in that project. It is referenced now by proj-b and the log handler is accessible but everytime I try to log something, it doesn't write to the specified file or to the console. I know my configuration is correct since I tried to create a junit test on proj-a and tested the log hander, it outputs what I need it to output, a log in a file and console display.

proj-b sample code:

```
public class TestServicePublisher {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        //  System.out.println("Test Service started.");
        //  Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8080/cas-service", new TestService());
        LogHandler.logDebug(TestServicePublisher.class, "main", "Starting Login Service");
        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8080/cas-service/login", new LoginService());
    }

}
```

and a sample of the logHandler in proj-a is as follows:

```
public static String logDebug(Class clazz, String methodName,
        Integer messageCode, List<String> messageAttributes) {
    List<String> classMethodAttributes = createClassMethodAttributes(clazz,
            methodName);
    String message = retrieveMessage(messageCode, messageAttributes,
            classMethodAttributes);
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(clazz);
    logger.debug(message);
    return message;
}
```

proj-a contains the log4j jar file as well as the log4j.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now have a solution to my woes. I've rechecked all the POMs that I have on all projects and found another instance of log4j dependencies on projectC.

Apparently, this came with slf4j and slf4j-jdk which is why I see logs of info level which is the same as the example [here](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html) in the slf4j manual. After removing these dependencies from the POM, I was able to run the main methods on any of the related projects without any problems.

Also I was getting the debugging info when I was running junits or main methods on projectA because it wasn't dependent on any other project which means it didn't include the slf4j and slf4j-jdk.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's a classpath and classloader issue.
Your log4j configuration file is in a jar built in project A.
Project B has the jar file from project A in its classpath, along with the log4j.jar file.
When your main class tries to initialize the log4j system it uses the classloader of your Main class to find the log4j configuration file, but it can't find it, thus your should get errors printed to stderr like:

*log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (TestServicePublisher).*

*log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.*

To verify this set your configuration file explicitly using the log4j.configuration system property.

Comment: Apparently I don't get those warnings when trying to run the main method of project B.

Comment: I've tried looking at it that way but every time I run the main method of projectB to start my service, it does go through the log handler of projectA but it doesn't give the error you are specifying here.

Comment: Did you try to debug log4j intialization? You can do that by setting the JVM property _log4j.debug_ to _true_.

Comment: Yes, I've added it in when running the program but apparently, the logs won't appear. If ever I created a main property on projectA and ran it with -Dlog4j.debug command, it runs and shows the log. If I try that on projectB, no logs appear. Additional info: If I add loggger.info("some message here") it appears on the console, debug level doesn't appear.

Comment: That's very strange. Setting the _log4j.debug_ system property should log messages to standard output (see the code in org.apache.log4j.helpers.LogLog).
Can you describe the layout of your application (where are the jar files, how you define the classpath and where is your log4j configuration file)? Did you try to put your log4j configuration file as a resource in the classpath (not in a jar file)?

Comment: I've already found the problem Oded Peer, thanks for the answers. :) I've left the answer here as well.

Comment: That was where I was trying to get :) I encountered slf4j problems a couple of months ago myself.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set the file at the run time instead of setting it in the configuration file.

In the code :

```
System.setProperty("file.name","your path");
```

In the log4j configuration file :

```
log4j.appender.appender_name.File = ${file.name}
```

Another method is to use the [setFile(String fileName)](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/FileAppender.html#setFile%28java.lang.String%29) function in the code and set the file name at runtime.

Comment: sad to say shamis, I couldn't use any of this as the properties file works if I use a junit test. But if I create a main method at projectA, it shows up with the error that Oded Peer stated in his post.